# Variational approach to the Laplace and Poisson equation in Jackson's book

Tags: electrostatics, charge, field-theory, variational-principle

In Section 1.12, Chapter 1 in Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics, he considered an "energy-like" functional,
$$
I[\psi]=\frac{1}{2}\int_V\nabla\psi\cdot\nabla\psi\ d^3x - \int_V g\psi\  d^3 x,
$$
and performed methods of variation with Green's first identity (as shown in Section 1.8 of the same chapter) to derive
$$\nabla^2\psi=-g,$$
which immediately implies that $\psi=\phi$ and $g=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$, where $\phi$ is the potential and $\rho$ is the charge density, according to the Poisson equation. I have three questions about the discussion above.

**1. Why must $\psi=\phi$ and $g=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$?** 
Although I know it is intuitive that the result should be the Poisson equation, I cannot mathematically be convinced. When he introduced the functional, neither $\psi$ or $g$ is specified, so I assumed that after a series of calculations to the final result, any function that satisfy certain conditions (i.e., $\psi(\mathbf{x})$ is well-behaved inside $V$ and on its surface $S$, and $g(\mathbf{x})$ is a specific "sourced" function without singularities within $V$, according to Jackson) will do.

**2. How did he come up with this functional?** 
I am guessing that he used the already-known Poisson equation with something similar to the least action principle but I don't know exactly how.

**3. Does the "energy-like" functional have any physical interpretation?** 
Plugging in $\psi=\phi$ and $g=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$ to the functional, you obtain
$$
I[\psi]=\frac{1}{2}\int_V\left|\mathbf{E}\right|^2\ d^3x -\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\int_V\rho\phi\ d^3x,
$$
which looks somewhat like a combination of two different expressions of the electrostatic potential energy except some differences in multiplication constants. Does this functional or its extremum mean anything?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. Of course the case $\rho=0$, that gives us Laplace equation means that the system tends to minimize energy (the first integral is the energy stored in the field). I wonder what is the physical meaning of $I[\phi]$ in Poisson case.

Comment: Take a look in my answer here : [Deriving Lagrangian density for electromagnetic field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34241/). Use the expression (044) to find the Lagrangian (volume) density for electrostatics ($\mathbf B=\boldsymbol 0,\mathbf j=\boldsymbol 0$) and integate in volume $V$ to produce your last equation.

Comment: Now that you say it, that is the lagrangian density of EM field written in the electrostatic case. I should have noticed that before. I wonder why these are called *energy-type* functional when its a lagrangian, I find that misleading.

Comment: Now I noticed that the functional is the integral of the Lagrangian density with respect to space coordinates, which produces the Lagrangian. But doesn't the least action principle requires stationary point of the action, which is the integral of the Lagrangian to time, instead of the Lagrangian itself?

Comment: The equations of motion (that is the differential Maxwell equations) are produced by the principle of least action with respect to the **Lagrangian density** as done for continuous systems, see what are the "coordinates" (field variables)  and what the equations of motion for these systems in my answer in the link: [Deriving Lagrangian density for electromagnetic field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34241/).....

Comment: ....The Lagrange function is used for discrete systems (single particle or many particles) with  coordinates like position, angle etc.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/271423/2451 and links therein.