# Follow-up on "Derivation of Lagrangian of electromagnetic field from Lorentz force"

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy

I have a follow-up on [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/513884/) post. The way I understand it, if one generally has a velocity-dependent potential $U(q, \dot q, t)$, then we can derive/define a *generalized* force $$Q_k = \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial U}{\partial \dot q_k} - \frac{\partial U}{\partial q_k}.$$
Now, this has a practical application when it comes to deriving the Lorentz force, as is done in the post I referenced to, but I don't understand yet why the generalized force that is derived there is the Lorentz force. I mean, when we take the generalized potential $U\left(q, \dot q, t\right) = q\left( \phi - \mathbf{\dot{\vec{r}}} \cdot \mathbf{\vec{A}} \right)$ and calculate the generalized force, why does it have to be the Lorentz force?

Comment: Because the potential you are using is for Lorentz force.

Comment: But if you want to re check, you can solve Lagrange's equation to derive lorentz force.

Comment: Related : [Deriving Lagrangian density for electromagnetic field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34241/deriving-lagrangian-density-for-electromagnetic-field/270950#270950).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the book by Landau Lifshitz volume 2 paragraph 17 formula (17.3),
$$\frac{d\vec p}{dt}=-\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial \vec A}{\partial t}-\nabla \phi+\frac{e}{c}[\vec v,\vec H]$$
which describes the equation of motion of a particle in an electromagnetic field. This chapter has a derivation of this formula.