# Is there a lagrangian density that yields Maxwell's equations coupled to sources, but also the correct dynamics of the 4-current?

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, electric-current, field-theory

We know that the EM-Lagrangian
\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{16 \pi} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{c} j_{\mu} A^{\mu}
\end{align}
correctly describes the evolution of the electromagnetic field in the presence of a given $j(x) = (c \rho(\vec{x}, t), \vec{j}(\vec{x}, t))$, which is externally specified, and not governed by the Lorentz-force (or rather its equivalent action on charge densities).
Treating $j^{\mu}$ as an independent field won't work, because then the e.l. equations would yield $A^{\mu} = 0$.

Is there any classical (classical as in: not quantized, no operators) lagrangian that yields the said equations, not only for the E.M. field, but also for the "sources"?

The next best thing I can think of is the EM-field coupled to a scalar field, with mass- and kinetic term for both and $j^{\mu} = \phi^* \partial_{\mu} \phi + \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi^*$ in the interaction term:
\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{16 \pi} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{c}( \phi^* \partial_{\mu} \phi + \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi^*) A_{\mu} + (\partial_{\mu} - A_{\mu})\phi^*(\partial^{\mu} - A^{\mu})\phi + (m^2)\phi^* \phi
\end{align}

But is there a lagrangian that is even closer? If not, why isn't this classical lagrangian used to do classical calculations? Doesn't it reproduce the dynamics that would follow from the Lorentz force?

To make more explicit what the lagrangian should yield: It should yield Maxwell's equations, coupled to sources, and additionally the behaviour consistent with a charge density that describes point particles with a trajectory $r_i$ by $j_i^{\mu}(x) = (c, \vec{v}_i(t))^T \delta(\vec{x} - \vec{x}_i(t))$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics#QED_action and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_electrodynamics#Lagrangian

Comment: @Andrew since I already mentioned the scalar QED lagrangian in my question, I guess the answer to the question "is there anything closer than this" is "no"?

Comment: You didn't write the right scalar lagrangian so I thought maybe you didn't know about minimal coupling. You need a term like $A_\mu A^\mu |\phi|^2$ as well coming from the covariant derivative.

Comment: I will write it out more explicit.

Comment: The QED and QED-scalar lagrangians are the answer to your question. You can view what you want to do -- replace the external current with dynamical fields -- in terms of the [Noether procedure](https://tinyurl.com/2p8rwm7s). This is an iterative procedure to discover consistent, gauge invariant lagrangians by adding terms order-by-order until you get a gauge invariant answer. For fermion-QED, the current is simply the Noether current for the $U(1)$ symmetry in the fermion case. For scalar-QED, there's a correction term proportional to $A^2$, which arises due to the derivative in the current.

Comment: 1. The "in matter" in the title suggests you might want to use a displacement tensor and a material law instead of just the $F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu}$ term.
2. From the Lagrangian you obtain the inhomogeneous Maxwell equations. What more exactly do you want to derive from it? Perhaps you specify the equations you want to obtain, this is unclear to me from what you write currently.

Comment: Related : [Deriving Lagrangian density for electromagnetic field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34241/deriving-lagrangian-density-for-electromagnetic-field).

Comment: Similar question and my answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/795485/does-classical-electrodynamics-have-a-lagrangian-that-gives-both-the-lorentz-for/795528

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering the title question: yes, but the exact Lagrangian depends on the dynamics.

If you want to describe a classical scalar field interacting with the electromagnetic field (for whatever reason), then you want the Lagrangian for [scalar electrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_electrodynamics). If you want to describe fermions, then you need the Lagrangian usually used in [quantum electrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics). This does not mean you need to quantize the fields: the action for QED will lead you to the theory in relativistic quantum mechanics of an electron interacting with the electromagnetic field. This is different from the theory of a classical scalar field interacting with the electromagnetic field.

If you want the theory for a charged particle interacting with the electromagnetic field, then you should add to the action the kinetic and mass terms for the particle (and eventual forces that you might want to consider) and the current in Maxwell's action will be the usual expression for the four-current of a point-particle.

In short, yes, you can get a Lagrangian describing both the electromagnetic field and the current. However, it does depend on your model for charged matter, as it should be: a charged fluid is expected to behave very differently from a point particle with finite charge. Different models for the source require different Lagrangians.

Comment: What would, in your answer, be the lagrangian for a charged fluid? Or has this just been an example of different behaviours of charged matter?

Comment: @Quantumwhisp It was just an example of different behaviors